# How to split a node content/right align in tikz tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=8em, text centered]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [bag] {$||$}
    child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
      child{node[bag] {$enabled$}}
      child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
          child{node[bag] {$tcas\_eq$}}
          child{node[bag] {$intent\_not\_known$}}
       }
    }
    child{node[bag] {$!$}
      child{node[bag] {$tcas\_eq$}}
    }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

How to make last two nodes' content separate?

I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but here is an answer using anchors to position the nodes relative to their left/right border instead of their center. I also use a modified `bag` style to ensure tighter spacing :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=8em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag_mod} = [text width=2em,
text centered]


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [bag] {$||$}
    child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
      child{node[bag] {$enabled$}}
      child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
          child{node[bag_mod,left] {$tcas\_eq$}}
          child{node[bag_mod,right] {$intent\_not\_known$}}
       }
    }
    child{node[bag] {$!$}
      child{node[bag] {$tcas\_eq$}}
    }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd say this is a perfect job for my package [forest](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree=math content
  [||
    [\&\&
      [enabled]
      [\&\&
        [tcas\_eq]
        [intent\_not\_known]
      ]
    ]
    [!
      [tcas\_eq]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

(The `math content` style is available only in the most recent version, 1.03. In older versions, you can either say `for tree={content format={\ensuremath{\forestoption{content}}}}`, or simply enclose each node's text in `$...$`.)

Comment: Nice package, Živanović!

Comment: @hpesoj626 No, ctan is down! :-(